# package intel-microcode / microcode data file

Tags: security

I have a braswell processor, an intel N3150. According to the microcode revision guidance there should be a microcode update:

https://newsroom.intel.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2018/04/microcode-update-guidance.pdf

```
Cherry View (Cherry Trail, Braswell) Intel® Atom® x5-Zxxxx CPU 406C3 01 Production --- --- 00000367

Cherry View (Cherry Trail,Braswell) Intel® Celeron® Processor Jxxxx, Intel® Celeron® Processor N3xxx, Intel® Pentium® Processor J3xxx, Intel® Pentium® Processor N3xxx, Intel® Atom® x5-E8000 Processor 406C4 01 Production --- --- 00000410
```

My CPUID is 406C3 ... i don't know why it is not the 406C4, but  both have a confirmed update by intel. But if i look in the newest microcode data file (25-04-2018) then these updates are not included:

```
/microcode-20180425$ iucode_tool -tr -l ./intel-ucode
iucode_tool: ./intel-ucode/list: no microcodes found in data file, skipping...
selected microcodes:
001: sig 0x00000650, pf mask 0x01, 1999-05-25, rev 0x0040, size 2048
002: sig 0x00000650, pf mask 0x02, 1999-05-25, rev 0x0041, size 2048
003: sig 0x00000650, pf mask 0x08, 1999-05-25, rev 0x0045, size 2048
004: sig 0x00000651, pf mask 0x01, 1999-05-25, rev 0x0040, size 2048
005: sig 0x00000652, pf mask 0x01, 1999-05-12, rev 0x002a, size 2048
006: sig 0x00000652, pf mask 0x02, 1999-05-17, rev 0x002c, size 2048
007: sig 0x00000652, pf mask 0x04, 1999-05-12, rev 0x002b, size 2048
008: sig 0x00000653, pf mask 0x01, 1999-06-28, rev 0x0010, size 2048
009: sig 0x00000653, pf mask 0x02, 1999-05-18, rev 0x000c, size 2048
010: sig 0x00000653, pf mask 0x04, 1999-05-20, rev 0x000b, size 2048
011: sig 0x00000653, pf mask 0x08, 1999-05-18, rev 0x000d, size 2048
012: sig 0x00000660, pf mask 0x01, 1999-05-05, rev 0x000a, size 2048
013: sig 0x00000665, pf mask 0x10, 1999-05-05, rev 0x0003, size 2048
014: sig 0x0000066a, pf mask 0x02, 1999-05-05, rev 0x000c, size 2048
015: sig 0x0000066a, pf mask 0x08, 1999-05-05, rev 0x000d, size 2048
016: sig 0x0000066a, pf mask 0x20, 1999-05-05, rev 0x000b, size 2048
017: sig 0x0000066d, pf mask 0x02, 1999-03-12, rev 0x0005, size 2048
018: sig 0x0000066d, pf mask 0x08, 1999-03-12, rev 0x0006, size 2048
019: sig 0x0000066d, pf mask 0x20, 1999-05-05, rev 0x0007, size 2048
020: sig 0x00000671, pf mask 0x04, 1998-08-11, rev 0x0014, size 2048
021: sig 0x00000672, pf mask 0x04, 1999-09-22, rev 0x0038, size 2048
022: sig 0x00000673, pf mask 0x04, 1999-09-10, rev 0x002e, size 2048
023: sig 0x00000681, pf mask 0x01, 1999-09-21, rev 0x000d, size 2048
024: sig 0x00000681, pf mask 0x04, 1999-09-21, rev 0x0010, size 2048
025: sig 0x00000681, pf mask 0x08, 1999-09-21, rev 0x000f, size 2048
026: sig 0x00000681, pf mask 0x10, 1999-09-21, rev 0x0011, size 2048
027: sig 0x00000681, pf mask 0x20, 1999-09-21, rev 0x000e, size 2048
028: sig 0x00000683, pf mask 0x08, 1999-10-15, rev 0x0008, size 2048
029: sig 0x00000683, pf mask 0x20, 1999-10-15, rev 0x0007, size 2048
030: sig 0x00000686, pf mask 0x01, 2000-05-05, rev 0x0007, size 2048
031: sig 0x00000686, pf mask 0x02, 2000-05-04, rev 0x000a, size 2048
032: sig 0x00000686, pf mask 0x04, 2000-05-04, rev 0x0002, size 2048
033: sig 0x00000686, pf mask 0x10, 2000-05-05, rev 0x0008, size 2048
034: sig 0x00000686, pf mask 0x80, 2000-05-04, rev 0x000c, size 2048
035: sig 0x0000068a, pf mask 0x10, 2000-11-02, rev 0x0001, size 2048
036: sig 0x0000068a, pf mask 0x20, 2000-12-07, rev 0x0004, size 2048
037: sig 0x0000068a, pf mask 0x80, 2000-12-07, rev 0x0005, size 2048
038: sig 0x00000695, pf mask 0x10, 2004-11-09, rev 0x0007, size 2048
039: sig 0x00000695, pf mask 0x20, 2004-11-09, rev 0x0007, size 2048
040: sig 0x00000695, pf mask 0x80, 2004-11-09, rev 0x0047, size 2048
041: sig 0x000006a0, pf mask 0x04, 2000-01-10, rev 0x0003, size 2048
042: sig 0x000006a1, pf mask 0x04, 2000-03-06, rev 0x0001, size 2048
043: sig 0x000006b1, pf mask 0x10, 2001-02-15, rev 0x001c, size 2048
044: sig 0x000006b1, pf mask 0x20, 2001-02-20, rev 0x001d, size 2048
045: sig 0x000006b4, pf mask 0x10, 2002-01-10, rev 0x0001, size 2048
046: sig 0x000006b4, pf mask 0x20, 2002-01-11, rev 0x0002, size 2048
047: sig 0x000006d6, pf mask 0x20, 2004-10-17, rev 0x0018, size 2048
048: sig 0x000006e8, pf mask 0x20, 2005-11-15, rev 0x0039, size 4096
049: sig 0x000006ec, pf mask 0x20, 2006-05-01, rev 0x0054, size 4096
050: sig 0x000006ec, pf mask 0x80, 2006-09-12, rev 0x0059, size 4096
051: sig 0x000006f2, pf mask 0x01, 2010-10-02, rev 0x005d, size 4096
052: sig 0x000006f2, pf mask 0x20, 2010-10-02, rev 0x005c, size 4096
053: sig 0x000006f6, pf mask 0x01, 2010-09-30, rev 0x00d0, size 4096
054: sig 0x000006f6, pf mask 0x04, 2010-10-01, rev 0x00d2, size 4096
055: sig 0x000006f6, pf mask 0x20, 2010-10-01, rev 0x00d1, size 4096
056: sig 0x000006f7, pf mask 0x10, 2010-10-02, rev 0x006a, size 4096
057: sig 0x000006f7, pf mask 0x40, 2010-10-02, rev 0x006b, size 4096
058: sig 0x000006fa, pf mask 0x80, 2010-10-02, rev 0x0095, size 4096
059: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x01, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00ba, size 4096
060: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x04, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00bc, size 4096
061: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x08, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00bb, size 4096
062: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x10, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00ba, size 4096
063: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x20, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00ba, size 4096
064: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x40, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00bc, size 4096
065: sig 0x000006fb, pf mask 0x80, 2010-10-03, rev 0x00ba, size 4096
066: sig 0x000006fd, pf mask 0x01, 2010-10-02, rev 0x00a4, size 4096
067: sig 0x000006fd, pf mask 0x20, 2010-10-02, rev 0x00a4, size 4096
068: sig 0x000006fd, pf mask 0x80, 2010-10-02, rev 0x00a4, size 4096
069: sig 0x00000f07, pf mask 0x01, 2002-07-16, rev 0x0012, size 2048
070: sig 0x00000f07, pf mask 0x02, 2000-11-15, rev 0x0008, size 2048
071: sig 0x00000f0a, pf mask 0x01, 2002-07-16, rev 0x0013, size 2048
072: sig 0x00000f0a, pf mask 0x02, 2002-08-21, rev 0x0015, size 2048
073: sig 0x00000f0a, pf mask 0x04, 2002-07-16, rev 0x0014, size 2048
074: sig 0x00000f12, pf mask 0x04, 2003-05-02, rev 0x002e, size 2048
075: sig 0x00000f24, pf mask 0x02, 2003-06-05, rev 0x001f, size 2048
076: sig 0x00000f24, pf mask 0x04, 2003-06-05, rev 0x001e, size 2048
077: sig 0x00000f24, pf mask 0x10, 2003-06-10, rev 0x0021, size 2048
078: sig 0x00000f25, pf mask 0x01, 2004-08-11, rev 0x0029, size 2048
079: sig 0x00000f25, pf mask 0x02, 2004-08-11, rev 0x002a, size 2048
080: sig 0x00000f25, pf mask 0x04, 2004-08-11, rev 0x002b, size 2048
081: sig 0x00000f25, pf mask 0x10, 2004-08-26, rev 0x002c, size 2048
082: sig 0x00000f26, pf mask 0x02, 2004-08-05, rev 0x0010, size 2048
083: sig 0x00000f27, pf mask 0x02, 2003-06-04, rev 0x0038, size 2048
084: sig 0x00000f27, pf mask 0x04, 2003-06-04, rev 0x0037, size 2048
085: sig 0x00000f27, pf mask 0x08, 2003-06-04, rev 0x0039, size 2048
086: sig 0x00000f29, pf mask 0x02, 2004-08-11, rev 0x002d, size 2048
087: sig 0x00000f29, pf mask 0x04, 2004-08-11, rev 0x002e, size 2048
088: sig 0x00000f29, pf mask 0x08, 2004-08-11, rev 0x002f, size 2048
089: sig 0x00000f32, pf mask 0x0d, 2004-05-11, rev 0x000a, size 2048
090: sig 0x00000f33, pf mask 0x0d, 2005-04-21, rev 0x000c, size 2048
091: sig 0x00000f34, pf mask 0x1d, 2005-04-21, rev 0x0017, size 7168
092: sig 0x00000f41, pf mask 0x02, 2005-04-21, rev 0x0016, size 5120
093: sig 0x00000f41, pf mask 0xbd, 2005-04-22, rev 0x0017, size 5120
094: sig 0x00000f43, pf mask 0x9d, 2005-04-21, rev 0x0005, size 2048
095: sig 0x00000f44, pf mask 0x9d, 2005-04-21, rev 0x0006, size 3072
096: sig 0x00000f47, pf mask 0x9d, 2005-04-21, rev 0x0003, size 3072
097: sig 0x00000f48, pf mask 0x01, 2006-05-08, rev 0x000c, size 3072
098: sig 0x00000f48, pf mask 0x02, 2008-01-15, rev 0x000e, size 3072
099: sig 0x00000f48, pf mask 0x5f, 2005-06-30, rev 0x0007, size 3072
100: sig 0x00000f49, pf mask 0xbd, 2005-04-21, rev 0x0003, size 2048
101: sig 0x00000f4a, pf mask 0x5c, 2005-12-14, rev 0x0004, size 2048
102: sig 0x00000f4a, pf mask 0x5d, 2005-06-10, rev 0x0002, size 2048
103: sig 0x00000f62, pf mask 0x04, 2005-12-15, rev 0x000f, size 3072
104: sig 0x00000f64, pf mask 0x01, 2005-12-15, rev 0x0002, size 3072
105: sig 0x00000f64, pf mask 0x34, 2005-12-23, rev 0x0004, size 3072
106: sig 0x00000f65, pf mask 0x01, 2006-04-26, rev 0x0008, size 2048
107: sig 0x00000f68, pf mask 0x22, 2006-07-14, rev 0x0009, size 2048
108: sig 0x00001632, pf mask 0x00, 1998-06-10, rev 0x0002, size 2048
109: sig 0x00010661, pf mask 0x01, 2010-10-04, rev 0x0043, size 4096
110: sig 0x00010661, pf mask 0x02, 2010-10-04, rev 0x0042, size 4096
111: sig 0x00010661, pf mask 0x80, 2010-10-04, rev 0x0044, size 4096
112: sig 0x00010676, pf mask 0x01, 2010-09-29, rev 0x060f, size 4096
113: sig 0x00010676, pf mask 0x04, 2010-09-29, rev 0x060f, size 4096
114: sig 0x00010676, pf mask 0x10, 2010-09-29, rev 0x060f, size 4096
115: sig 0x00010676, pf mask 0x40, 2010-09-29, rev 0x060f, size 4096
116: sig 0x00010676, pf mask 0x80, 2010-09-29, rev 0x060f, size 4096
117: sig 0x00010677, pf mask 0x10, 2010-09-29, rev 0x070a, size 4096
118: sig 0x0001067a, pf mask 0x11, 2010-09-28, rev 0x0a0b, size 8192
119: sig 0x0001067a, pf mask 0x44, 2010-09-28, rev 0x0a0b, size 8192
120: sig 0x0001067a, pf mask 0xa0, 2010-09-28, rev 0x0a0b, size 8192
121: sig 0x000106a4, pf mask 0x03, 2013-06-21, rev 0x0012, size 14336
122: sig 0x000106a5, pf mask 0x03, 2013-06-21, rev 0x0019, size 10240
123: sig 0x000106c2, pf mask 0x01, 2009-04-10, rev 0x0217, size 5120
124: sig 0x000106c2, pf mask 0x04, 2009-04-10, rev 0x0218, size 5120
125: sig 0x000106c2, pf mask 0x08, 2009-04-10, rev 0x0219, size 5120
126: sig 0x000106ca, pf mask 0x01, 2009-08-25, rev 0x0107, size 5120
127: sig 0x000106ca, pf mask 0x04, 2009-08-25, rev 0x0107, size 5120
128: sig 0x000106ca, pf mask 0x08, 2009-08-25, rev 0x0107, size 5120
129: sig 0x000106ca, pf mask 0x10, 2009-08-25, rev 0x0107, size 5120
130: sig 0x000106d1, pf mask 0x08, 2010-09-30, rev 0x0029, size 4096
131: sig 0x000106e5, pf mask 0x13, 2013-08-20, rev 0x0007, size 7168
132: sig 0x00020652, pf mask 0x12, 2013-06-26, rev 0x000e, size 8192
133: sig 0x00020655, pf mask 0x92, 2013-06-28, rev 0x0004, size 3072
134: sig 0x00020661, pf mask 0x01, 2009-10-23, rev 0x0104, size 5120
135: sig 0x00020661, pf mask 0x02, 2011-07-18, rev 0x0105, size 5120
136: sig 0x000206a7, pf mask 0x12, 2018-02-07, rev 0x002d, size 12288
137: sig 0x000206d6, pf mask 0x6d, 2018-01-30, rev 0x061c, size 18432
138: sig 0x000206d7, pf mask 0x6d, 2018-01-26, rev 0x0713, size 19456
139: sig 0x000206f2, pf mask 0x05, 2013-06-18, rev 0x0037, size 13312
140: sig 0x000306a9, pf mask 0x12, 2018-02-07, rev 0x001f, size 13312
141: sig 0x000306c3, pf mask 0x32, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0024, size 23552
142: sig 0x000306d4, pf mask 0xc0, 2018-01-18, rev 0x002a, size 18432
143: sig 0x000306e4, pf mask 0xed, 2018-01-25, rev 0x042c, size 15360
144: sig 0x000306e6, pf mask 0xed, 2013-06-19, rev 0x0600, size 11264
145: sig 0x000306e7, pf mask 0xed, 2018-02-16, rev 0x0713, size 16384
146: sig 0x000306f2, pf mask 0x6f, 2018-01-19, rev 0x003c, size 33792
147: sig 0x000306f4, pf mask 0x80, 2018-01-22, rev 0x0011, size 17408
148: sig 0x00040651, pf mask 0x72, 2018-01-18, rev 0x0023, size 21504
149: sig 0x00040661, pf mask 0x32, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0019, size 25600
150: sig 0x00040671, pf mask 0x22, 2018-01-21, rev 0x001d, size 12288
151: sig 0x000406e3, pf mask 0xc0, 2017-11-16, rev 0x00c2, size 99328
152: sig 0x00050653, pf mask 0x97, 2018-01-29, rev 0x1000140, size 30720
153: sig 0x00050654, pf mask 0xb7, 2018-01-26, rev 0x2000043, size 28672
154: sig 0x00050662, pf mask 0x10, 2018-01-22, rev 0x0015, size 31744
155: sig 0x00050663, pf mask 0x10, 2018-01-22, rev 0x7000012, size 22528
156: sig 0x00050664, pf mask 0x10, 2018-01-22, rev 0xf000011, size 22528
157: sig 0x00050665, pf mask 0x10, 2018-01-22, rev 0xe000009, size 18432
158: sig 0x000506c9, pf mask 0x03, 2017-03-25, rev 0x002c, size 16384
159: sig 0x000506e3, pf mask 0x36, 2017-11-16, rev 0x00c2, size 99328
160: sig 0x000706a1, pf mask 0x01, 2017-12-26, rev 0x0022, size 73728
161: sig 0x000806e9, pf mask 0xc0, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0084, size 98304
162: sig 0x000806ea, pf mask 0xc0, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0084, size 97280
163: sig 0x000906e9, pf mask 0x2a, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0084, size 98304
164: sig 0x000906ea, pf mask 0x22, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0084, size 96256
165: sig 0x000906eb, pf mask 0x02, 2018-01-21, rev 0x0084, size 98304
```

So my question would be, if ubuntu has access to all updates like the manufacturer for the intel-microcode package or depends on the microcode data file from intel? I don't know if my manufacturer will ever deliver a bios update. Is there hope that intel will deliver in the future all microcode updates, which are mentioned in the microcode revision guidance, also in the microcode data file? Why intel did it still not?

Answer (score 0):

The intel-microcode package only publishes microcode that has been deemed safe for general install by Intel, i.e. the ones Intel is distributing/has distributed in their "Linux microcode release" file.

You can find the microcode update for your N3150 in BIOS-mod sites.  Use at your own risk (you might permanently damage your motherboard if you get the BIOS modding wrong).

You can add extra microcode to /usr/share/misc/intel-microcode.bin and intel-microcode will use it, but since nobody knows why Intel does not deem that microcode "ready for general, wide distribution", it could cause severe problems for your system.  Use at your own risk, and don't complain if it does permanent damage of whatever sort due to firmware incompatibilities.

And never buy from whatever vendor you got that board from again.  If you don't vote with your wallet, you have no room to complain...

Comment: Hallo, thank you for your answer. The board is from gigabyte. Yes, i will never buy a board from gigabyte again. But where i can get the microcode, if the microcode is not in the microcode data file?

Answer (score 0):

Use UBU bios modification tool.

Link: https://www.win-raid.com/t154f16-Tool-Guide-News-quot-UEFI-BIOS-Updater-quot-UBU.html

But yes, I have checked! 02-April-2018 microcode updates are not included in Linux* Processor Microcode Data File Version: 20180425 (Latest) thus, UBU Bios tool can not provide it!

Not availabe at: https://github.com/platomav/CPUMicrocodes too....

Check those 2 links regularly, they can announce new microcodes, if availabe!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the links. I found in the github repository a microcode update for my CPU and the microcode is working.

Comment: Looking at that tool I was wary.  I'd never use any BIOS updater that did not come from the OEM.  Have you checked with the OEM of your system board?